# Issue Calculating from Rows and Columns(Summing two columns with the third of a different row)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

With reference to my previous question
[Adding columns resulting from GROUP BY clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13892128/adding-columns-resulting-from-group-by-clause/13892514#13892514)

```
SELECT AcctId,Date,
   Sum(CASE
         WHEN DC = 'C' THEN TrnAmt
         ELSE 0
       END) AS C,
   Sum(CASE
         WHEN DC = 'D' THEN TrnAmt
         ELSE 0
       END) AS D
FROM   Table1 where AcctId = '51'
GROUP  BY AcctId,Date
ORDER  BY AcctId,Date
```

I executed the above query and got my desired result..

```
  AcctId       Date         C        D
    51       2012-12-04   15000      0
    51       2012-12-05   150000  160596
    51       2012-12-06    600        0
```

now I have a another operation to do on the same query i.e.

I need the result to be like this

```
  AcctId   Date                                Result

    51       2012-12-04    (15000-0)->       15000  
    51       2012-12-05   (150000-160596) + (15000->The first value)  4404
    51       2012-12-06     600-0         +(4404 ->The calculated 2nd value) 5004
```

Is it possible with the same query??.

Comment: If this were an Oracle question, this could be solved easily using the [`MODEL` clause](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12245888/521799). `LAG()` is probably not going to work in this case...

Comment: But, I need to execute it on MSSqlServer..

Comment: If this was a SQL Server 2012 question, you could probably use `SUM(...) OVER (ORDER BY ...)`.

Comment: @AndriyM: So the windowing clauses were finally added to T-SQL window functions?

Comment: @LukasEder: [Yes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx "OVER Clause (Transact-SQL)"), if you were asking specifically about support of `ORDER BY` in *aggregate* window functions (as opposed to *ranking* window functions, which have supported (in fact, required) ORDER BY since their introduction in SQL Server 2005).

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 , is it possible  ? Please provide with an Example.

Comment: @vstsdev - The name for the type of the query you are doing is running totals. This is a pain to do in < SQL Server 2012 and best done in the application. If you must do it in SQL the following answwers may help. [One](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860966/calculate-a-running-total-in-sqlserver), [Two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357516/subquery-or-leftjoin-with-group-by-which-one-is-faster/7454564#7454564)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use recursive CTE

```
;WITH cte AS
 (
  SELECT AcctId, Date,
     Sum(CASE
           WHEN DC = 'C' THEN TrnAmt
           ELSE 0
         END) AS C,
     Sum(CASE
           WHEN DC = 'D' THEN TrnAmt
           ELSE 0
         END) AS D,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY AcctId, Date) AS Id 
  FROM   Table1 where AcctId = '51'
  GROUP  BY AcctId, Date
  ), cte2 AS
 (
  SELECT Id, AcctId, Date, C, D, (C - 0) AS Result
  FROM cte
  WHERE Id = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT c.Id, c.AcctId, c.Date, c.C, c.D, (c.C - c.D) + ct.Result
  FROM cte c JOIN cte2 ct ON c.Id = ct.Id + 1
  )
  SELECT *
  FROM cte2
```

Simple example on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/45911/1/0)